# Get the highest id from a specific where clause

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have 4 records on my **guests** database.

[image]

I'm trying to query to the guest that has `note_display = 1` and have the highest id.

---

## I've tried

```
$last_note = DB::table('guests')->where('note_display','=',1)->where('id', DB::raw("(select max(`id`) from guests)"))->first();
```

I got

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

---

I'm a lil stuck now, any hints will be a huge helps ?

Comment: Perhaps I'm not thinking about it correctly, but wouldn't `Guest::where('note_display', 1)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();` give you what you need?

Comment: @camelCase that's exactly what I thought when I read the question. Not sure why the OP is using raw statements for something the query builder does so easily.

Comment: You guys are totally right. I made this harder than it actually is. I totally forgot about `orderBy('id', 'desc')`

Comment: Easy to do! I've been there many times, glad we could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use `raw` in this query. You can run a simple query like

```
Guest::where('note_display', 1)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
```

And it will return the Guest with the highest `ID` and having `note_display` = `1`.

Answer (score 1):

The raw sql string should be something like `SELECT * FROM guests WHERE note_display = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`  it looks you are getting only rows with `note_display = 1` inside a sub-query `WHERE id={the maximum id present in the table}`

Answer (score 1):

It select the maximum of id where the the note_display is = 0, so the try to get non-object error happened.

If you're insisting to go with `raw` try this!

```
$last_note = DB::table('guests')->where('id', DB::raw("(select max(`id`) from guests where note_display = '1')"))->first();
```

Comment: Plus one for still maintain my DB:raw, and still come up with the solution. :)

Comment: @ihue glad u got the solution, my friend